# Query continues to select rows despite 'where not null'

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm using a query command in google sheets to take the left variable of a text string, convert it to a number and sum it with other columns. When I attempt to use a query command of `where Col1 is not null` it continues to pull each row leaving a sheet full of zeros. What am I missing? Here's the full formula

```
=Query(ArrayFormula(value(left(T2:AC))),"select Col1+Col2+Col3+Col4+Col5+Col6+Col7+Col8+Col9+Col10,Col9 where Col1 is not null label Col1+Col2+Col3+Col4+Col5+Col6+Col7+Col8+Col9+Col10 'Total', Col9 'Q9'")
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the `is not null` clause in your formula? https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#where

Comment: Updated. I had removed it from my sheet since it was causing issues and forgot to add it back in before copying to here.

Comment: Add a sample data of `T2:T` and the result of the first column of `ArrayFormula(value(left(T2:AC)))`

Comment: Updated with data and requested formula (couldn't embed the image). Looks like the `value` function is converting every empty cell into a 0. So then when the array gets passed to the `query` command, it is not null.

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer regarding this. Could you please confirm whether that solves your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[VALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094220?hl=en) converts empty strings (`""`) to `0`, as you can see on of the examples from the official Docs.

Because of this, before using `VALUE` to a cell, you should first check if the cell is empty. One option would be to use [ISBLANK](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093290?hl=en):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(E2:F),,VALUE(LEFT(E2:F))))
```

[image]

Comment: @jhaeff You're welcome. Glad your issue was solved!